# when column function evaluation order guarantees

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is

```
df.withColumn("x", when(cond1, val1)
                  .when(cond2, val2)
                  .when(cond3, val3))
```

equivalent to

```
df.withColumn("x", when(cond1, val1)
                  .otherwise(when(cond2, val2)
                            .otherwise(when(cond3, val3)))
```

i.e. does the order of "when" expressions guarantee an evaluation order on them?

The first piece of code looks a lot cleaner but I am unsure if it will work as I expect it to.

Comment: I guess you can write a test to be sure :)

Comment: SQL is a declarative language. Might be that in one case this is correct and not in another if Catalyst decides it's more optimal. I am interested in guarantee on this from the API.

Comment: Nope, it will always check conditions in the same order. The result is deterministic.

Comment: @GaëlJ Is there documentation anywhere on this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Yes". Both the code pieces will evaluate in the defined order.